# If statement for is_author of a post

Tags: author, conditional-tags

I want to show something in the sidebar of a post only if the author of the post equals a specific author or username. I was looking at `is_author()` but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the posts author (inside the loop) with the `global $post;`

```
echo $post->post_author
```

If your sidebar comes after your main content (in code), then you could populate a global array (not the best solution, but ok).

```
// in the loop: Add each author to the global $post_authors array
$post_authors[] = $GLOBALS['post']->post_author;

// in your sidebar:
if ( in_array( 'Author Name', $GLOBALS['post_authors'], true ) )
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I can't this to work. I replace 'Author Name' with the author Im trying to target but it doesn't return anything on the posts by that author.

Comment: what? Please post some sample code in your answer. I don't get a single word.

Comment: I used your snippet and replaced `Author Name` with the name of an author from my site. I placed an element inside the brackets but it doesnt return anything when the `Author Name` is equal to the author name of the post.

Comment: Shure, that the `Author Name` is really the authors name and not the `display_name`, `first_name`, `user_login`, etc?

Comment: How about doing a little `var_dump/var_export/print_r` yourself and see what you get out of it?

Comment: omg. You shouldn't `var_dump` the result of setting a var. You should dump the `$post` object to see the actual author name. Mate, after reading your Q for quite a time now: You should really start digging into the basics of php. This - well invested 2 hours - will save you and us a whole load of time. [Here are the basics - read them and you will understand.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/langref.php).

Comment: True I didn't know what html meant 3 months ago but you're the expert and I applied your answer exactly as you gave and it didn't work so not reason to get pissy. =)

Comment: `var_dump($post_authors[] = $GLOBALS['post']->post_author);` <- don't do this. Instead please spend _2_ (not more needed) hours in front of the manual. 2 of your questions (incl. comments and your testing) waste more time than you'd need there. The sys is already at the point that it tells us to stop writing here and move on in chat > flag poppin' up for mods. More wasted time. So it's not _pissed_, it's part of my answer: Spend time on the manual or lower your expectations or ask (for yourself) easier Qs. If you're not doing one of those, you won't get satisfying answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Do the following only on Single post page
 */
if( is_single() ){
    global $post;

    $specific_username = 'fred';

    $post_author_id = $post->post_author;
    $post_author_username = get_the_author_meta('user_login', $post_author_id );

    if( $post_author_username == $specific_username ){
        //SHOW SOMETHING
    }
}
```